# Skrollr background: position property applied to an image does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I am trying to animate opacity and parrallax position property of a few images using the scrollr.

Opacity works flawlessly on img and div tags, but position property will not work.

I tried applying the background-position property to img tag and div tag but it just doesn't work.

```
<div class="image1" data-bottom="opacity:0;background-position: 0px -250px;" data-center="opacity:1;background-position: 0px 0px;" data-top="opacity:0;background-position: 0px 250px;"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Eq87X/3/

Thanks

Comment: @Daedalus Did the above fiddle work for you? I have tried it in Firefox, Chrome, Safari with no luck.

Comment: The background of the picture moves as the picture fades.  This has worked fine for me in chrome; if it isn't what you desire, you need to be more specific in your question.  Also, I tested this in Chrome 32.

Comment: @Daedalus. Position property should move the image or div, which ever it is applied to. When applied to a DIV - it is only moving the background image inside the div and not the entire div. When applied to an IMG, it doesn't to anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

The position doesn't need to be fixed or absolute. It can be relative.

As an example:

```
 data-150-top="background-position: 0px -250px;"
 data-350-top="background-position: 0px 0px;"
```

In other words, the example sets data to move between **150px** and **350px**

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move an element, you need to give it a position `absolute` or `fixed`. Have a look at my [Simple parallax tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/), that might help.

Comment: This example is broken on iOS (iPad with iOS 8). It doesn't scroll at all.